# Querying master.sys.databases view in SQL Server 2008 R2 from c# is not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, master-db

I'm using the code below to find if a database exists but the `ExecuteNonQuery` always returns -1.

I've seen the `master.sys.databases` view and it has the database `POS`

```
SqlConnection tmpConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");

sqlCheckDBQuery = "SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = \'aspnetdb\'";

using (tmpConn)
{
    try
    {
        tmpConn.Open();
        tmpConn.ChangeDatabase("master");
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("SQLServer Express Database is either not installed or not running!", "Database Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        Application.Exit();
    }

    using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCheckDBQuery, tmpConn))
    {
        int exists = sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (exists <= 0)
            databaseExists = false;
        else
            databaseExists = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this particular instance you can use a scalar query instead of a data reader.

```
sqlCheckDBQuery = "SELECT count(1) FROM master.sys.databases where name = 'aspnetdb'";
var count = (int)sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar();
databaseExists = count > 1;
```

Comment: that worked like a charm but I wonder why the SqlDataReader was not returning any row (I tried it with ExecuteReader)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ExecuteScalar()` and change the query to run a `COUNT(*)`.

`ExecuteScalar` will bring back the rows affected.

`ExecuteNonQuery()` will bring back -1 for `SELECT`'s.

Comment: +1 `ExecuteScalar()` is the way to go here. I completely forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` is the wrong method to use. Use `ExecuteReader()` instead: e.g.:

```
var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.Read())
    ....
```

Comment: but is's still returning me 0 rows, it should return 1 row

Comment: @UzairFarooq remove the backslashes from "SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = \'aspnetdb\'" so it reads "SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = 'aspnetdb'"

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlCheckDBQuery = "SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = \'aspnetdb\'";
```

Why are you using backslashes here? The name of the database is `aspnetdb` so this should be:

```
sqlCheckDBQuery = "SELECT * FROM master.sys.databases where name = 'aspnetdb'";
```

Also as has been mentioned in other answers you cannot use [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) here since that will return always -1 for select statements.